# Unable to compile main.cpp for avr_bridge

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to follow the "Hello Tutorial" for avr_bridge, and when I run "make" after creating main.cpp, I get this error message:

uav@UAV-PC-2:~/ros_tutorials/avr_bridge_callResponse$ make
[  5%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/firmware.dir/src/main.cpp.o
/home/uav/ros_tutorials/avr_bridge_callResponse/src/main.cpp:26: error: variable or field ‘response’ declared void
/home/uav/ros_tutorials/avr_bridge_callResponse/src/main.cpp:26: error: ‘Msg’ was not declared in this scope
/home/uav/ros_tutorials/avr_bridge_callResponse/src/main.cpp:26: error: ‘msg’ was not declared in this scope
/home/uav/ros_tutorials/avr_bridge_callResponse/src/main.cpp: In function ‘void setup()’:
/home/uav/ros_tutorials/avr_bridge_callResponse/src/main.cpp:48: error: ‘response’ was not declared in this scope
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/firmware.dir/src/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/firmware.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10487/unable-to-compile-main.cpp-for-avr_bridge/) by [UAV](https://answers.ros.org/users/789/uav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2011-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

avr_bridge is in the middle of being phased out in favor of the new, soon to be released/announced rosserial pkg.  We are in the middle writing the documentation for rosserial which you can find [here](http://ros.org/wiki/rosserial_arduino).  You should be able to use most of the documentation by the end of today.

Anyway, it looks like your cmake file is just incorrect or you havent generated the avr_ros files.  However, I wouldn't spend any time working with avr_bridge.  I will actually be deleting the avr_bridge repo next week after we formally announce rosserial.

---

Originally posted by [adasta](https://answers.ros.org/users/52/adasta/) with karma: 508 on 2011-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1